# How to change sqlite3_temp_directory?

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I was trying to VACUUM my database and got the following error:

"org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_FULL]  Insertion failed because database is full (database or disk is full)"

According to http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/quot-Vacuum-quot-command-is-failing-with-quot-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full-quot-td48238.html , we can change the sqlite3_temp_directory(Name Of The Folder Holding Temporary Files).

Can someone help me on how to change this in a LINUX environment?

Comment: you can use pragma but should use [pragma_temp_store](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store) instead of [pragma_temp_store_directory](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store_directory) as latter one is deprecated.

Comment: Also see https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temporary_file_storage_locations

Comment: And in case you're getting this error despite **not** being low on disk space, see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739973/database-or-disk-is-full-on-vacuum-with-plenty-of-free-space), as that's a sign of a corrupted database.

Comment: I do not want to change the PRAGMA_SETTINGS. I have to do this by changing the sqlite3_temp_directory

Comment: According to the first page Shawn linked, in the absence of using `PRAGMA temp_store_directory` or setting `sqlite3_temp_directory`, under Linux it should look for environment variables `SQLITE_TMPDIR` or `TMPDIR`.

Comment: Probably you are refering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394517/setting-sqlite-temp-store-directory.  I still do not understand the solution.

Comment: How can we change the SQLITE_TMPDIR  or TMPDIR?

Comment: I added SQLITE_TMPDIR  as an environment variable. Thanks all for the help!